# get data from read more buttons in goutte web scraper in php

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte

I have a page that contains multiple articles and read more buttons.
I want to click on every read more button and get the post text from that page and I don't know how to do that.
this is my php code.thank you all

```
$client = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
     'timeout' => 60,
));
$client->setClient($guzzleClient);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/');
$crawler->filter('article > div > p > span > a')->each(function ($node)  use ($client,$crawler)
{
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('read more')->link());
    echo $crawler->html();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/');
});
```

Comment: What issue are you getting right now?

Comment: @AmitMerchant I don't know how to do that really

Comment: what does the `echo $crawler->html();` say?

Comment: @stef i just wanted to test that out... do you know how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two cases while clicking to read more button

1- Articles will be loaded request will be send to new URL with some parameter like http://www.example.com?page=2 then page=3 and so on.

2- Articles will be loaded via Ajax request.

If you are having case 1 then we can easily click on read more button and get next number of articles and so on. Here is your edited code, please take in mind you have to write original button text in selectLink function, like `<button>Read More</button>` then Read More will go as parameter.

```
$client = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
 'timeout' => 60,
 ));
$client->setClient($guzzleClient);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/');
$crawler->filter('article > div > p > span > a')->each(function 
($node)  use ($client,$crawler)
{
$articles = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('As text appear on button')->link());
echo $articles->html(); // this crawler object will have next loaded articles

$article2 = $client->click($articles->selectLink('As text appear on button')->link());

// article2 will have have next latest articles then article3 and so on.

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com/');
});
```

As we know Guzzle does not support Javascript enabled sites that means case 2 cannot be possible with goutte click functionality and we need to trace ajax request URL and Parameters and then send Post or Get request to that URL and filter articles based on some selector.